# Are there any rules of appointing a learnt scholar from Non-Brahmin origin as a clergy or priesthood for others?

Tags: brahmins, varnashrama

By Non-Brahmin, I mean all other varnas and not specific to one caste or clan.
Please give references from scriptures, if any.

Comment: Some social reformers tried to do upanayanam to people from Non-brahmin origin and teach them mantras required for priest, but failed.  The main problem with people from Non-brahmin origin in doing the job of a priest in Hindu temple is that they have to (i) hang on to temple, irrespective of income they get, (ii) they have to prepare prasadam for the deity on their own or get it prepared 2 times a day, after taking bath, (iii) they have to follow vegetarian diet., etc. :-).

Comment: @srimannarayanakv namaste, my question was not about social reform. I know that much of it is actually drama by politicians. My question was to know is there any shastra-sammat way for the appointing any other caste as priests or clergy.

Comment: You may not find such references in Puranas or other rules of Hinduism.  As far as Veda is concerned, there is no temple concept.

Comment: Furthermore you need to lookup definition of Brahmin as per scripture. I hope you do realize that birth alone does not decide one's Varna, and texts are filled with examples of individuals moving from one Varna to another.

Comment: @Carmensandiego namaste ! Yes, that is the reason I mentioned the word origin. I am aware that there are various interpretations of Varna in various schools of Hinduism and I respect that. However, I was going by the orthodox standard of smarta tradition as they have it birth based. I was looking for something called 'gaun brahmin' which is anyone who attained the attributes of a Brahmin without being from a Brahmin origin. thank you !